# Why do we need visibleCells function (UICollectionView)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Currently i have collection view consisting of 4 cells. This is a horizontal collectionView with one cell per display, so each time there is one cell should show itself. When i rotate my device , that also this one cell per screen mode is on. and every time I say to my collectionView to show visible cells, it shows me different arrays. (from portrait to horizontal 2 cells in array, from horizontal to portrait even 3 cell in array). If this visibleCells array every time different why do we need it? And why it every time different ( i mean from portr to hor and vice versa) 
thats my code

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addSubview(collectionView)

    view.addSubview(pageControl)

    view.addSubview(skipButton)
    view.addSubview(nextButton)
   print( view.constraints)

    nextButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(nil, left: nil, bottom: nil, right:
        view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    nextButtonTopAnchor = nextButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16)
    nextButtonTopAnchor?.isActive = true
    nextButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    nextButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
    skipButton.anchorWithConstantsToTop(nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 16, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0)
    skipButtonTopAnchor = skipButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 16)
    skipButtonTopAnchor?.isActive = true
    skipButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    skipButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

     pageControl.anchorWithConstantsToTop(nil, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 28, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 28)

    print("\(pageControlConstant) L")
    pageControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait || (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) ) {  pageControlBottomAnchor = pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0)
    } else if  UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) == false  {
  pageControlBottomAnchor =     pageControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5)
    }
    pageControlBottomAnchor?.isActive = true

    collectionView.anchorToTop(view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor)
    registerCells()

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}  
override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator)
{

    if pageControl.currentPage != pages.count {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape || (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation)) {
        self.nextButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 0
        self.skipButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 0
          self.pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 5
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        } else {
            self.nextButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 16
            self.skipButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 16
             self.pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
                self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
        }
    }

    if pageControl.currentPage == pages.count {


        var mySpecialCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:IndexPath(item: pages.count, section: 0)) as! LoginCell


        if  (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape || (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft)) ) 
 {
            mySpecialCell.someShit = "landSpace"
            } else {
            mySpecialCell.someShit = "portrait"

        }

        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
     collectionView.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.pageControl.currentPage, section: 0)
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)

        if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape || (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeLeft)) ) 
{

        } else {

        }
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }

 }



func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    let pageNumber = Int(targetContentOffset.pointee.x / view.frame.width)
  print(  view.constraints)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageNumber)
    if pageNumber == pages.count {



        nextButtonTopAnchor?.constant = -40
        skipButtonTopAnchor?.constant = -40
        pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 50


        print(pageControlBottomAnchor)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    } else {

        if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape || (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) )  {
        pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 5
            self.nextButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 0
            self.skipButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 0
        } else if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat && UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation) || !UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape ) {
            self.nextButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 16
            self.skipButtonTopAnchor?.constant = 16
            pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 0
        }



    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)

    }

}
fileprivate func moveControlConstraintsOffScreen() {

    pageControlBottomAnchor?.constant = 150
    pageControlBottomAnchor?.isActive = true
}
fileprivate func registerCells() {
      collectionView.register(PageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    collectionView.register(LoginCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: loginCellId)
    collectionView.register(LoginCellLandscape.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: loginCellLandscapeId)

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("I will display \(cell) for \(indexPath)")
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("I did end displaying \(cell) for \(indexPath)")

}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pages.count + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

           let loginCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: loginCellId, for: indexPath)
        return loginCell

 }



    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! PageCell

    let page = pages[indexPath.item]
    cell.page = page

    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the question as asking why `UICollectionView` has a `visibleCells` function...

It sounds like you don't need it. It's not useful in every app. But sometimes it is. Here's one example:

Suppose your cells show data that represents events over time-- Twitter posts in a timeline, maybe. And suppose that your UI includes a field showing how old each event is-- "20s ago", "3m ago", etc. To keep those times accurate, you could set up a timer to update the values at regular intervals. What should happen when the timer fires?

You could just tell the table view to reload its data. That would be effective but it's a lot more work than necessary. You don't need to reload the entire cells, you just need to update one field in the cell. But which cells? Only the ones that are visible. So, ask the collection view which cells are visible, and update the time field in those cells.

It's probably not useful to ask which cells are visible when the device rotates, because as you observe, the visible cells change then. Still, someone might have a use for it in that situation that I just haven't thought of.